# Command line ifconfig problems - Not detecting all NICs

Tags: server, command-line, ifconfig

I am in the command line of Ubuntu server edition 10.04 and I have 3 Nic cards installed. When I type ifconfig it only detects one: Eth0. I tried doing sudo apt-get update, this did not work. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Are your NIC's bonded?

Answer (score 7):

Try `ifconfig -a`. it will show all interface cards even if they are down.

Answer (score 2):

`ifconfig` doesn't necessary detect NICs plugged in, particularly if they aren't supported. If they show up when you run `lspci`, you might need to get the proper drivers for them.

Answer (score 1):

try with this one, `ifconfig -a` and then you Up the network interface by executing this in terminal `sudo ifconfig eth1 up` and change eth1 to whatever network interface that shown on first command. If you already have eth0 up, then try to up another interface for example wlan0, eth1 or else. I'm not sure. This depends on the `ifconfig -a` result.