# No internet connection after updating Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, networking, ethernet

I updated my system a few days ago and cannot access to internet anymore using my Ethernet cable (nor with wifi, but it never worked).
I have Windows on the same computer, which still recognizes the cable and allows internet connection.

ifconfig only shows "lo" local lookback element, without any other paragraph. I have reset the etc/resolve.conf file, restarted network manager, etc. with no success.

Comment: If you only have "lo" it means that Ubuntu cant see/use network card.
Check drivers or physical damage/connection. List ethernet adapters: lspci | grep -i eth

Comment: I have "Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros Device e0b1 (rev 10)" So the device is still here. I should see drivers...

Comment: maybe try https://askubuntu.com/a/45769/747387

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reverted to the previous Linux kernel.

I had the problem with "Ubuntu with Linux 4.15.0-24".
I'm now using "Ubuntu with Linux 4.13.0-45".

`ifconfig` shows both `enp111s0` and `lo` again, and I can use wired connection.

Note that I didn't install any network driver for this previous version.